# Парсинг кодировки и присваивание наименования

Tags: python, pandas

Использую вот такую конструкцию:
Создаю пустой столбец
`df['Результат'] = ''`

Записываю в него результат проверки на вхождение части строки

`df['Результат'] = df['Информация'].str.contains('AAA' or 'AA', case - False)`

В результате получаю заполненный столбец со значениями True или False

Что не удается сделать:

На основе результата (T\F) выполнить запись в новый столбец или изменить начальный (df['Результат']) на соответствующее значение ('AAA' or 'AA': 'Буквы 'А'')  по словарю

Хотелось бы использовать сложную конструкцию проверок if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятна задача и конструкция, которую вы используете. Но само заполнение данными по булевому столбцу можно сделать примерно так:

```py
df['Результат'] = ''
mask = df['Информация'].str.contains('AAA' or 'AA', case - False)
df.loc[mask, 'Результат'] = "Буквы 'А'"
```

Comment: Благодарю, этот способ позволяет решить мою задачу

Comment: А как можно это реализовать через словарь и конструкцию IF? При этом подходе код будет короче

Comment: 'AAA' or 'AA' Это просто заглушки, а case - это учет регистра (опечатки где вместо '=' допущено '-' прошу игнорировать)

Comment: Дополните вопрос - покажите, какие у вас есть варианты заполнения данных и по каким условиям. Я пока не очень понимаю, какая тут система )

Comment: Есть кодировка выполненной задачи в виде записи: DD.FGH.JTTUY.Z1.AAA + какой текст. Эти данные находятся в отдельной колонке датайфрейма. Ее я хочу разобрать и записать в несколько соседних столбцов (вновь создаваемые). Всего их 5 (как и значений в кодировке разделенных точкой

Comment: В каждой из 5ти групп свой набор уникальных вариантов. Например, в первой части ”DD.” зашита информация о типе процесса (DD : «какое-то название процесса»)

Comment: В конечном итоге необходимо будет построить сводную таблицу на основе данных этих (тут вопросов нет)